# Generate classes by alphabet extracting href element

Tags: jquery, list, variables, alphabetical

So I have a list, example:

```
<ul>
 <li href="pages/ade.html">ade</li>
 <li href="pages/ate.html">ate</li>
 <li href="pages/aca.html">aca</li>
 <li href="pages/bes.html">bes</li>
 <li href="pages/bon.html">bon</li>
 <li href="pages/cas.html">cas</li>
<ul>
```

And I'm usign jquery to get the href attribute and then add a class to that element.

```
$("li > a[href^='/pages/a']").parent().addClass( "brand-a" );
$("li > a[href^='/pages/b']").parent().addClass( "brand-b" );
$("li > a[href^='/pages/c']").parent().addClass( "brand-c" );
```

So I don't want to write a function for each letter and I was thinking that I can use alphabet to do this. I found this looking around, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
```

Thanks

Comment: Your example markup doesn't have a nested <a> tag.  You have the href on the li elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you must loop, maybe something like this:

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('').forEach(function(letter){
    $("li > a[href^='/pages/" + letter + "']").parent().addClass( "brand-" + letter + "" );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that works!. One more question is the same for a capital letter? I have some URLs that are like this /collections/vendors?q=Mad and is not working. Obviously, I'm changing the code to /collections/vendors?q=" + letter + " but it doesn't work

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to add a case insensitivity flag inside the regex part of the selector ```$("li > a[href^='/pages/" + letter + "' i ]")```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the href to get the brand letter

```js
$('li > a[href*="pages/"]').each(function() {
  var brand = this.href.split('pages/')[1].charAt(0);
  $(this).parent().addClass('brand-' + brand);
});
```

```css
.brand-a a { color: red }
.brand-b a { color: green }
.brand-c a { color: orange }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="pages/ade.html">ade</a></li>
  <li><a href="pages/ate.html">ate</a></li>
  <li><a href="pages/aca.html">aca</a></li>
  <li><a href="pages/bes.html">bes</a></li>
  <li><a href="pages/bon.html">bon</a></li>
  <li><a href="pages/cas.html">cas</a></li>
  <ul>
```